# UITableView clear data

Tags: iphone

How to clear whole tableview data and reload with new one?

Answer (score 25):

Clear your data before calling reloadData, and now the user will see the table get cleared and re-populated with fresh data.

```
myArray = nil;
[myTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 3):

use [tableView reloadData] method on ui table view

Comment: Just be careful doing it while in Edit mode.

Answer (score 3):

This was my wrok around which worked.
set cell = nil;

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` is a property, and

```
[cell.contentView clearsContextBeforeDrawing];
```

does nothing except of returning its value.

Answer (score 0):

ok.. but.. we need the solution for this.. if we add the cells in runtime, i have received the output with the same cells in first and last cells of the uitableview..

you can clear the cell before add any subviews

Example:

```
[mytableview.contentView clearsContextBeforeDrawing];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the value of the reused cell and if its not the same - then recreate it.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
MyLog(@"Start Table: cellForRowAtIndexPath: %d", indexPath.row);

NSString *MyIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyIdentifier %i", indexPath.row];
UILabel *lblNew;
lblNew = [UILabel new];
UILabel *lblCell;
lblCell = [UILabel new];

MyTableCell *cell = (MyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:[lblNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];       
} 
else 
{
    lblNew = [lblNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    for (id label in [cell.contentView subviews])   
    {
        if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) 
        {
            lblCell = label;
        }
    }
    if (![lblNew.text isEqualToString:lblCell.text])
    {
        cell = [[[MyTableCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[lblNameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**: Not sure it's the best way or not, But I'm using this code to clear and roload Data:

```
fileprivate func clearTable() {
    self.tableviewData.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had double entries on selection after scrolling. Now the Display is as clean as expected!
Used the workaround

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell = nil;
```

and also (btw: clearsContextBeforeDrawing as standalone it did not work

```
[cell.contentView clearsContextBeforeDrawing];
```

in Simulator i have the impression of more accurate reaction on cell selection.
Thank you!